# Deserializing an array that contains some non-deserializable objects (salvaging the deserializable parts)

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

### Background

I am attempting to write an object deserialization in such a way that if an array of objects contains **some** objects that (due to code change) can't be deserialized then those references in the array will become null rather than throwing an exception; allowing the remainder of the object to be salvaged.

### What I've tried

I have tried to use a custom serialization/deserialization in the hope that I can catch the exception and apply my custom "make it null" logic. The code for this is included below. However the first point at which I seem able to catch the exception is once the entire array deserialization has already failed.

```
public class AppleHolder implements Serializable{
    Apple[] apples=new Apple[5];
    double otherData=15;
    
    
    public AppleHolder(){
        Apple goodApple=new Apple("GoodApple","tastyGood");
        BadApple badApple=new BadApple("BadApple","tastyBad");
        
        apples[0]=goodApple;
        apples[1]=goodApple; // multiple references to same object intentional
        apples[2]=goodApple;
        apples[3]=badApple;
        apples[4]=badApple;
    }
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o)
            throws IOException {
        
        o.writeObject(apples);
        o.writeObject(otherData);
    }
    
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        apples = (Apple[]) o.readObject();
        otherData = (double) o.readObject();
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        
        /*
         * (1) First run serialize()
         * (2) Change the badApple's serialVersionUID to 2
         * (3) Run deSerialize(()
         */
        
        serialize();
        
        
        //deSerialize();
        
    }
    
    public static void serialize() throws Exception{
        AppleHolder testWrite = new AppleHolder();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testfile");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(testWrite);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        
    }
    
    public static void deSerialize() throws Exception{
        AppleHolder testRead;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("testfile");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        testRead = (AppleHolder) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        
        System.out.println("--Read object--");
        System.out.println("propertyOne: " + testRead.apples[0].getPropertyOne());
        
    }

}

public class Apple implements Serializable {
    private String propertyOne;
    private String propertyTwo;
    
    public Apple(String propertyOne, String propertyTwo) {
        this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
        this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
        validate();
    }
    
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o)
            throws IOException {
        
        o.writeObject(propertyOne);
        o.writeObject(propertyTwo);
    }
    
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        propertyOne = (String) o.readObject();
        propertyTwo = (String) o.readObject();
        validate();
    }
    
    private void validate(){
        if(propertyOne == null ||
                propertyOne.length() == 0 ||
                propertyTwo == null ||
                propertyTwo.length() == 0){
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    
    public String getPropertyOne() {
        return propertyOne;
    }
    
    public String getPropertyTwo() {
        return propertyTwo;
    }
}

public class BadApple extends Apple {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    
    
    public BadApple(String propertyOne, String propertyTwo) {
        super(propertyOne, propertyTwo);
    }
    

}
```

My exception was

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: customserialisation.BadApple; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 2
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at customserialisation.AppleHolder.readObject(AppleHolder.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at customserialisation.AppleHolder.deSerialize(AppleHolder.java:79)
    at customserialisation.AppleHolder.main(AppleHolder.java:61)
```

Which I think would allow me to salvage "otherData" by catching the exception but not the partial `apples` array.

### What I tried 2

As per Alexander Torstling's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20914324/2187042) I attempted to recreate the array from deserialised pieces

```
apples=new Apple[appleCount]
for(int i=0; i<appleCount; i++) {
  try { 
    apples[i]= o.readObject());
  } catch(Exception e) {
    //Add null or nothing or what you want.
    apples[i]=null;
  }
}
```

However, this does not consume any o.readObject() that the badApple may have had within it (in this case the two strings) as such the deserialized data gets out of sync and in my case I get a casting exception because `otherData = (double) o.readObject();` reads the `String` that should have been part of BadApple because that was never consumed from the stream.

### Question

How can I salvage a serialized array in which only some of the objects are deserializable? Thereby getting an array with null entries for the non deserializable parts. Within my array I have several references to the same object in a single array, it is essential that this is preserved in the deserialization process.

So going into serialization I have

```
[GoodApple]
[GoodApple]  
[GoodApple]  
[BadApple]
[BadApple]
```

And coming out of deserialization I want (because badApple has changed and cannot be deserialised

```
[GoodApple]
[GoodApple]  
[GoodApple]  
[null]
[null]
```

I want this to provide a fallback where backwards compatibility cannot be achieved or a 3rd party modification to my program that was previously installed is removed

Comment: A related question to this, in which the same problem is solved using the Kryo serialization library (which I found to be considerably faster) can be found here;[Deserializing an array that contains some non-deserializable objects using Kryo (salvaging the deserializable parts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949311/deserializing-an-array-that-contains-some-non-deserializable-objects-using-kryo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely but since you don't want to interrupt the array-deserialization I don't think you can catch and continue in any meaningful way.  Other options that I then see is writing a custom array deserialization routine or to write a custom deserializer for BadApple.  If being backwards compatible is hard,  what about just setting fields to bogus values and set a flag indicating a "bad entry"  ? Is the problem that you can't modify the BadApple class?

EDIT: By the way, if you want't to have a look at how array deserialization is done, check out ObjectInputStream#readArray. Looks possible to replicate and modify that code to support you scenario, but if I were you I would stick with supporting deserialization of the old version instead, seems less messy.

EDIT2: I haven't been able to come up with any really straight forward standard technique for nulling out the bads without editing BadApple. I think you might have to roll your own collection serialization with custom de-serialization which skips bad apples when de-serializing. A sketch of how it would look if you would do it directly in AppleHolder (I would make a separate list type with this functionality, but I thought this example was clearer):

```
public class AppleHolder implements Serializable{
  static int START_OF_APPLE_MAGIC=120;
  List<Apple> apples=new ArrayList<Apple>();
  double otherData=15;

  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o)
        throws IOException {
    o.writeInt(apples.size());
    for(Apple a: apples) {
      o.write(START_OF_APPLE_MAGIC);
      o.writeObject(a);
    }
    o.writeObject(otherData);
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    int appleCount = o.readInt();
    apples = new ArrayList<Apple>(appleCount);
    for(int i=0; i<appleCount; i++) {
      try { 
        while(o.read() != START_OF_APPLE_MAGIC) {
          //fast forward to boundary. Maybe add a max here to avoid infinite loops.
        }
        apples.add((Apple) o.readObject());
      } catch(SomethingWentBadException e) {
        //Add null or nothing or what you want. Look out for failures caused by
        //the value of START_OF_APPLE_MAGIC contained in ordinary fields
        apples.add(null);
      }
    }
    otherData = (double) o.readObject();
  }
}
```

I used a list since it would be easier if you don't read back all objects and don't use null placeholders (unknown exact readback size). The example should work with arrays though with only minor tweaks.

EDIT3: I updated the example with a magic boundary value. This is really hackish. I used a byte value, since otherwise we cannot be sure if the object deserialization read an even amount of bytes or not (alignment problem).

Comment: I have clarified my question re-uncertainty

Comment: @RichardTingle I understand now, please see my updates.

Comment: This seems to get upset at the next good `o.readObject();`. In this case `otherData = (double) o.readObject();` ends up with the exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`. I'm assuming because each apple contains two strings which are not consumed by the badApple deserialisation process because the bad apple is never deserialised

Comment: Yes,  I think you're right.  I looked around and can't find any way of skipping an object in the stream. All the 'readFields' and related methods can only be called from the class itself according to the APIs. The problem now shifts to detecting end of object. Perhaps if you can prefix every object write with the size,  so you know how many bytes to skip? Ill think of a good way of doing that.

Comment: @RichardTingle Ok so I can come up with two decent strategies. One is to prefix each "Apple" with a semi-unique magic byte sequence. When the deserialization fails, read byte by byte until you hit the magic bytes. This should mean that you are at the next apple. But it's not guaranteed, so you might get false positives and handle those. The more correct version is to prefix each apple with size, and to do mark() before reading an apple, and reset() and skip the bad apple after deserialization failure. This requires access to the underlying stream, which can be done in various hackish ways.

Comment: @RichardTingle (continued). Additionally, this second method requires knowing the size of the write before performing it, so you'll need to write to an intermediate stream (like BAOS) before writing to the ObjectOutputStream. It's getting complicated... So maybe just try the magic byte approach? I'll update the pseudo code with something like this.

Comment: @RichardTingle I think that you might also have a problem that you don't know where the deserialization failed, so you're alignment might be off and your subsequent read might not begin at the start of the next object. That's why I went for a byte value as the marker, since reading a single byte always "hits the mark" :)

Comment: Hey, where did your AppleDivider comment go?

Comment: I deleted it while I played around with your edit 3, which is awesome btw. The risk of the number 120 just "turning up in the stream" is also only a small risk because it is only a problem when the fallback is being used, which will hopefully be rare

Comment: You should see the horror of what I was playing about with before, trys within trys within trys. This is actually quite elegant by comparison

Comment: @RichardTingle Cool that you think its awesome! I hope it works out for you. This proved to be more complicated than I initially thought. They obviously didn't consider this use case when designing the serialization system. It would be so much easier if they just had a "skipObject()"-method!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change `BadApple` and need to solve it in `AppleHolder`, I think you're out of luck.  But if you can, have a look at the [javadoc for `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), in particular:

> Classes that need to designate a replacement when an instance of it is
>   read from the stream should implement this special method with the
>   exact signature.
>
> `ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object readResolve() throws
>   ObjectStreamException;`

So adding this to `BadApple` should do the trick:

```
private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException { return null; }
```

EDIT: you may need to have it implement `Serializable` explicitly for this to work, so this may not be what you want.

Comment: This solves 50% of my problems and is good to be going on with. Sometimes I control badApple and I will use that in those cases

Comment: If this affects the serialisation process rather than the deserialisation process (i.e. the alternative lives witin the serialised file) I can make it part of the coding standard and solve 100%. I shall have a play

Comment: I think that readResolve is called after deserialization, so I believe that you need to make readObject not throw first.

Comment: Looking into this readResolve() seems to be called always, rather than only if something bad happens, so my bad apple ends up null even if something bad didn't happen